# Error 500 for basic REST service in Lift Scala MongoDB while createRecord

Tags: scala, lift

The REST service object code is:

```
object Account extends RestHelper {
  def createUser = {
    for {
      username <- S.param("username") ?~ "username parameter missing" ~> 400
      number <- S.param("number") ?~ "number parameter missing"
    } yield {
      val u = GeoFence.createRecord.name(username)
      u.save
      u.asJSON
    }
  }

  serve {
    case Req("api" :: "hello" :: Nil, "json", GetRequest) => JString("hi")
    case Req("api" :: "accounts" :: "new" :: Nil, "json", GetRequest) => createUser()
  }
}
```

This is the exception I see on browser whenever I'm trying to run the REST service.

The exception is pointing to line 27 which is:

> val u = GeoFence.createRecord.name(username)
>
> u.save

HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /api/accounts/new.json. Reason:

```
(class: net/liftweb/record/Record$class, method: toForm signature: (Lnet/liftweb/record/Record;Lscala/Function1;)Lscala/xml/NodeSeq;) Incompatible object argument for function call
```

Caused by:

java.lang.VerifyError: (class: net/liftweb/record/Record$class, method: toForm signature: (Lnet/liftweb/record/Record;Lscala/Function1;)Lscala/xml/NodeSeq;) Incompatible object argument for function call
    at smartfamily.model.GeoFence.(GeoFence.scala:21)
    at smartfamily.model.GeoFence$.(GeoFence.scala:19)
    at smartfamily.model.GeoFence$.(GeoFence.scala)
    at smartfamily.api.Account$$anonfun$createUser$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Account.scala:27)
    at smartfamily.api.Account$$anonfun$createUser$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Account.scala:25)
    at net.liftweb.common.Full.map(Box.scala:478)
    at smartfamily.api.Account$$anonfun$createUser$1.apply(Account.scala:25)
    at smartfamily.api.Account$$anonfun$createUser$1.apply(Account.scala:24)
    at net.liftweb.common.Full.flatMap(Box.scala:480)
    at smartfamily.api.Account$.createUser(Account.scala:24)
    at smartfamily.api.Account$$anonfun$1.apply(Account.scala:35)
    at smartfamily.api.Account$$anonfun$1.apply(Account.scala:33)
    at net.liftweb.http.rest.RestHelper$class.apply(RestHelper.scala:472)
    at smartfamily.api.Account$.apply(Account.scala:21)
    at smartfamily.api.Account$.apply(Account.scala:21)
    at net.liftweb.util.NamedPF$$anonfun$applyBox$1.apply(NamedPartialFunction.scala:97)
    at net.liftweb.util.NamedPF$$anonfun$applyBox$1.apply(NamedPartialFunction.scala:97)
    at net.liftweb.common.Full.map(Box.scala:478)
    at net.liftweb.util.NamedPF$.applyBox(NamedPartialFunction.scala:97)
    at net.liftweb.http.LiftServlet.doService(LiftServlet.scala:220)
    at net.liftweb.http.LiftServlet$$anonfun$doIt$1$1.apply$mcZ$sp(LiftServlet.scala:129)
    at net.liftweb.http.LiftServlet$$anonfun$doIt$1$1.apply(LiftServlet.scala:129)
    at net.liftweb.http.LiftServlet$$anonfun$doIt$1$1.apply(LiftServlet.scala:129)
    at net.liftweb.util.TimeHelpers$class.calcTime(TimeHelpers.scala:344)
    at net.liftweb.util.Helpers$.calcTime(Helpers.scala:34)
    at net.liftweb.util.TimeHelpers$class.logTime(TimeHelpers.scala:353)
    at net.liftweb.util.Helpers$.logTime(Helpers.scala:34)
    at net.liftweb.http.LiftServlet.doIt$1(LiftServlet.scala:128)
    at net.liftweb.http.LiftServlet.service(LiftServlet.scala:137)
    at net.liftweb.http.provider.HTTPProvider$$anonfun$service$2$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(HTTPProvider.scala:69)
    at net.liftweb.http.provider.HTTPProvider$$anonfun$service$2$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(HTTPProvider.scala:68)
    at net.liftweb.http.provider.HTTPProvider$$anonfun$service$2$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(HTTPProvider.scala:68)
    at net.liftweb.util.ThreadGlobal.doWith(ThreadGlobal.scala:71)
    at net.liftweb.http.URLRewriter$.doWith(Req.scala:1063)
    at net.liftweb.http.provider.HTTPProvider$$anonfun$service$2.apply$mcV$sp(HTTPProvider.scala:67)
    at net.liftweb.http.provider.HTTPProvider$$anonfun$service$2.apply(HTTPProvider.scala:67)
    at net.liftweb.http.provider.HTTPProvider$$anonfun$service$2.apply(HTTPProvider.scala:67)
    at net.liftweb.util.ThreadGlobal.doWith(ThreadGlobal.scala:71)
    at net.liftweb.http.provider.HTTPProvider$class.service(HTTPProvider.scala:63)
    at net.liftweb.http.LiftFilter.service(LiftServlet.scala:689)
    at net.liftweb.http.provider.servlet.ServletFilterProvider$$anonfun$doFilter$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ServletFilterProvider.scala:67)
    at net.liftweb.http.provider.servlet.ServletFilterProvider$$anonfun$doFilter$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ServletFilterProvider.scala:62)
    at net.liftweb.http.provider.servlet.ServletFilterProvider$$anonfun$doFilter$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ServletFilterProvider.scala:62)
    at net.liftweb.http.CoreRequestVarHandler$$anonfun$apply$12$$anonfun$apply$13$$anonfun$apply$14$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(Vars.scala:513)
    at net.liftweb.util.ThreadGlobal.doWith(ThreadGlobal.scala:71)
    at net.liftweb.http.CoreRequestVarHandler$$anonfun$apply$12$$anonfun$apply$13$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Vars.scala:512)
    at net.liftweb.util.ThreadGlobal.doWith(ThreadGlobal.scala:71)
    at net.liftweb.http.CoreRequestVarHandler$$anonfun$apply$12$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Vars.scala:511)
    at net.liftweb.util.ThreadGlobal.doWith(ThreadGlobal.scala:71)
    at net.liftweb.http.CoreRequestVarHandler$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Vars.scala:510)
    at net.liftweb.util.ThreadGlobal.doWith(ThreadGlobal.scala:71)
    at net.liftweb.http.CoreRequestVarHandler$class.apply(Vars.scala:509)
    at net.liftweb.http.RequestVarHandler$.apply(Vars.scala:428)
    at net.liftweb.http.provider.servlet.ServletFilterProvider$$anonfun$doFilter$1.apply$mcV$sp(ServletFilterProvider.scala:61)
    at net.liftweb.http.provider.servlet.ServletFilterProvider$$anonfun$doFilter$1.apply(ServletFilterProvider.scala:61)
    at net.liftweb.http.provider.servlet.ServletFilterProvider$$anonfun$doFilter$1.apply(ServletFilterProvider.scala:61)
    at net.liftweb.http.CoreRequestVarHandler$$anonfun$apply$12$$anonfun$apply$13$$anonfun$apply$14$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(Vars.scala:513)
    at net.liftweb.util.ThreadGlobal.doWith(ThreadGlobal.scala:71)
    at net.liftweb.http.CoreRequestVarHandler$$anonfun$apply$12$$anonfun$apply$13$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Vars.scala:512)
    at net.liftweb.util.ThreadGlobal.doWith(ThreadGlobal.scala:71)
    at net.liftweb.http.CoreRequestVarHandler$$anonfun$apply$12$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Vars.scala:511)
    at net.liftweb.util.ThreadGlobal.doWith(ThreadGlobal.scala:71)
    at net.liftweb.http.CoreRequestVarHandler$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Vars.scala:510)
    at net.liftweb.util.ThreadGlobal.doWith(ThreadGlobal.scala:71)
    at net.liftweb.http.CoreRequestVarHandler$class.apply(Vars.scala:509)
    at net.liftweb.http.TransientRequestVarHandler$.apply(Vars.scala:432)
    at net.liftweb.http.provider.servlet.ServletFilterProvider$class.doFilter(ServletFilterProvider.scala:60)
    at net.liftweb.http.LiftFilter.doFilter(LiftServlet.scala:689)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:440)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:926)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)

**UPDATE 1**

Well it was resolved by the excellent lift community at the given link.

http://groups.google.com/group/liftweb/browse_thread/thread/e70cc3763734fdd9

Comment: The exception will be much simpler to read if you insert four spaces in front of 'java.lang.VerifyError...'

Answer (score 0):

The first line in your exception is:

```
smartfamily.model.GeoFence.<init>(GeoFence.scala:21)
```

This is where you'll have to look for the problem. Your call to net.liftweb.record.Record.toForm apparently doesn't match the signature you compiled it against. I would guess that you're running your application with the wrong version of lift. Either that or your lift jar file is corrupt.